# get value that occurs more than one in a list?

Tags: java, list

What are the the best methods to get values that occur more than once in a large list of words **without slowing my run time**?.  My file contains **1xx,xxx  words** and I put them into a linked list.  Now, I want to get only the words that **occur more than once** out of that list.

For example, if a list contains:

```
....This is is is just a test test....
```

I want to get `is` and `test` and put them into another list using an iterator.

I don't know if my code is right, and I think that this is not the best solution to approach for this problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
   Word s = word.get(i);
   Word s1 = word.get(i+1);
   if(s.equals(s1)) {
      newWord.add(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code as well ?

Comment: You can do it while putting words in the list itself in first place.

Comment: Put them all into ```HashSet``` instead of list and check the return value of ```add()``` method.

Answer (score 1):

Put them all into `HashSet` instead of list and check the return value of [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) method.

```
HashSet<Word> wordSet = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    if(!wordSet.add(word.get(i)){
         //Found duplicate
    } 
}
```

Note that you can also do it during/instead of creation of the list of the words.

Comment: really nice approach, i'll try it.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why it's taking for ever to run.

Comment: Check implementation of equals() and hashcode() in the Word class. If they have all same hashcode then adding element would.traverse the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

Build a `hashmap` with the word as key and it count as value.

```
for(each word in list)
{
    count = 1;
    if(map.contains(word))
    {
        count = map.get(word);
    }
    else 
        count = 1;
    map.put(word,count);
}
```

Then iterate over the `hashmap` and check if values is 1, and add the word to your list.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i did try 'Map' and it worked but i just want to use 'Iterator' for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort the list, then finding duplicates is quick and easy.

Comment: I sorted the list already, now every duplicate is grouped together.